# rails using .try object with images and different versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, try-catch, carrierwave

I wanted to look through some data, and wanted to check if there's an image. I'm currently using .try:

`obj.obj_images.try(:first).try(:photo_url)`

But, because I'm using carrierwave, and have set up multiple image versions, how do I add my `:medium` into it?

I tried

`obj.obj_images.try(:first).try(:photo_url(:medium))`

But that's clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that `:medium` is an argument of the `photo_url` method? If so:

```
obj.obj_images.try(:first).try(:photo_url, :medium)
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect.. that was fast! :) I'll have to check this off in 9 minutes.